# Generating a 1-dim array with explanatory arrows and text and large braces

Tags: tex

I am still learning tikz and often have to use complicated solutions where I am sure are more simple ones. From my latest tikz files I picked one to ask for tips what I can do better, to learn about features of tikz.

The general layout should stay the same. Slight changes are fine. Suggestions should be about syntax.

I convert this file using

```
pdflatex 1.tex
```

and the result is a pdf/png like this

[image: result]

#### General prologue for all my tikz PNGs

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
  \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
  \usetikzlibrary{trees}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{gpcHintergrund}{RGB}{205,229,244}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}

\begin{document}
```

#### tikz intro

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      background rectangle/.style={fill=gpcHintergrund}, show background rectangle,
      every node/.style={align=center, font=\small, minimum height=1.5em, minimum width=1.0cm,node distance=0cm},
        line/.style={ draw, line width=3pt },
        cell/.style = {rectangle, fill=white, draw, text width=1.0cm,outer sep=0pt},
        capx/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm, color=black!60,outer sep=0pt},
      scale=0.95,
      every node/.append style={transform shape},   % (1) scale here first approx. lines stay.
    %  every node/.append style={draw},
    ]
```

#### Center nodes/boxes

```
   \node at (0,0) [cell] (n1) {10};
   \node[right=of n1,cell] (n2) {20};
   \node[right=of n2,cell] (n3) {30};
   \node[right=of n3,cell] (n4) {40};
   \node[right=of n4,cell] (n5) {50};
   \node[right=of n5,cell] (n6) {60};
   \node[right=of n6,cell] (n7) {70};
   \node[right=of n7,cell] (n8) {80};
   \node[right=of n8,cell,fill=black!20,text=black!60] (ne) {end};
```

Could this series of `right=of`s be replaced by a totally different approach?

#### The text above and below with arrows

```
\node[above=of n2.west,yshift=1.0cm] (lb2) {lower\_bound(20)};
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-1pt] (lb2) -- (n2.north west);

\node[above=of n7.west,yshift=1cm] (ub7) {upper\_bound(60)};
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-1pt] (ub7) -- (n7.north west);

\node[above=of n4,yshift=0.5cm] (er4) {equal\_range(40)};
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-3pt] (er4) -- (n4.north west);
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-3pt] (er4) -- (n5.north west);


\node[below=of n3.west,yshift=-1.0cm] (lb25) {lower\_bound(25)};
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-1pt] (lb25) -- (n3.south west);

\node[below=of n7.west,yshift=-1.0cm] (ub65) {upper\_bound(65)};
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-1pt] (ub65) -- (n7.south west);

\node[below=of n4.east,yshift=-0.7cm] (er45) {equal\_range(45)};
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-3pt] ([xshift=0.4ex]er45.north) -- ([xshift=0.4ex]n5.south west);
  \path [->,draw,shorten <=-3pt] (er45.north) -- (n5.south west);
```

`equal_range(40)` could have two straight/parallel arrows, not diagonal. Their tips must point exactly where they are now, but the backs could move apart until parallel. I know about `|-` and `-|` but did not manage to straighten the lines.

#### The curly braces "gefunden" and "nicht gefunden"

```
\draw[decoration={brace},decorate,color=black!50]
  ([yshift=1.3cm]ne.north west) -- node[right=6pt] {gefunden} ([yshift=0.2cm]ne.north west);

\draw[decoration={brace,mirror},decorate,color=black!50]
  ([yshift=-1.3cm]ne.south west) -- node[right=6pt] {nicht gefunden} ([yshift=-0.2cm]ne.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The placing of the braces using `yshift`s looks very bad to me. What could be a better way?

Comment: @Jamal I left the `%`s in there on purpose. I should be easy to copy the full src out. Don't you think that was a good idea? If not, ok...

Comment: I was just unaware of that and assumed they were entirely irrelevant.  You can still add them back if you wish.

Comment: @Jamal No, now that I see it I like the beauty of it better then the practicality. Its only a handful of lines...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here are some points. Do ask if you need clarification:

- `tikz` loads `pgf`, so having `\usepackage{pgf}` is redundant.
- Personally I'd say only load the libraries you need. You may also use a single `\usetikzlibrary`, but that is I think just a matter of preference.
- The `arrows.meta` library has replaced `arrows` (the latter still works, but is considered deprecated, see the manual)
- Instead of the `right=of`, you can use the `chains` library, and place the nodes on a chain, using a loop to reduce the code if desired. There are other methods of achieving the same thing I think, but `chains` works fine here.
- An alternative of the `yshift`s and `xshift`s is to use relative coordinates, e.g. `++(1cm,0)` is the point 1cm to the right of the previous active coordinate.
- For the vertical arrows: The coordinate `(a-|b)` has the y-coordinate of `a` and the x-coordinate of `b`. See how it's used in the code.
- Instead of having `above=of x,yshift=y`, use `above=y of x`, e.g. `above=1cm of n2.west`.
- I also added an additional style for the arrows, where the length for `shorten <` is made an argument. In `myarrow/.style={->,shorten <=#1}`, `#1` indicates the argument, and the style is used as `myarrow={<some length>}`.
- I modified `\path[draw]` to `\draw`.
- For e.g. `lower_bound(20)` you could alternatively make the arrow and node in the same path, i.e.

  ```
  \draw [myarrow=-1pt] (n2.north west) -- ++(0,0.7cm) node[above] {lower\_bound(20)};
  ```

  This is merely a matter of preference though. One might find it clearer to separate the nodes from the arrows, as in your original code.
- The `standalone` class is very handy for making PDFs consisting of only a `tikzpicture`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  backgrounds,
  decorations.pathreplacing,
  chains}
\definecolor{gpcHintergrund}{RGB}{205,229,244}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      background rectangle/.style={fill=gpcHintergrund}, show background rectangle,
      every node/.style={align=center, font=\small, minimum height=1.5em, minimum width=1.0cm,node distance=0cm},
        line/.style={ draw, line width=3pt },
        cell/.style = {rectangle, fill=white, draw, text width=1.0cm,outer sep=0pt,on chain}, % added on chain
        capx/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm, color=black!60,outer sep=0pt},
        myarrow/.style={->,shorten <=#1},
      scale=0.95,
      every node/.append style={transform shape},   % (1) scale here first approx. lines stay.
    ]

\begin{scope}[start chain]
\foreach [count=\i] \x in {10,20,...,80}
  \node [cell] (n\i) {\x};

\node[cell,fill=black!20,text=black!60] (ne) {end};
\end{scope}

\node[above=1cm of n2.west] (lb2) {lower\_bound(20)};
  \draw [myarrow=-1pt] (lb2) -- (n2.north west);

\node[above=1cm of n7.west] (ub7) {upper\_bound(60)};
  \draw [myarrow=-1pt] (ub7) -- (n7.north west);

\node[above=0.5cm of n4] (er4) {equal\_range(40)};
  \draw [myarrow=-3pt] (er4.south-|n4.north west) -- (n4.north west);
  \draw [myarrow=-3pt] (er4.south-|n5.north west) -- (n5.north west);


\node[below=1cm of n3.west] (lb25) {lower\_bound(25)};
  \draw [myarrow=-1pt] (lb25) -- (n3.south west);

\node[below=1cm of n7.west] (ub65) {upper\_bound(65)};
  \draw [myarrow=-1pt] (ub65) -- (n7.south west);

\node[below=0.7cm of n4.east] (er45) {equal\_range(45)};
  \draw [myarrow=-3pt] (er45.north) ++(0.45ex,0) coordinate (tmp) -- (tmp|-n5.south west);
  \draw [myarrow=-3pt] (er45.north) -- (n5.south west);

\draw[decoration={brace},decorate,color=black!50]
  (ne.north west) ++(0,1.3cm) -- node[right=6pt] {gefunden} ++(0,-1.1cm);

\draw[decoration={brace,mirror},decorate,color=black!50]
  (ne.south west) ++(0,-1.3cm) -- node[right=6pt] {nicht gefunden} ++(0,1.1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool thanks! "dont load pgf" ok. "libs you need", my code is only an excerpt with other tikzs. "arrows.meta" ok. "chains" super! "++" useful for future. "vertical arrows" whow! "above=y of x" I have to read carefully. "\draw" good. "node and arrow same path" very good. "standalone class" I will read up there too. Many thanks, I will work those in and memorize your suggestions. Very, very good.